# Notation and meaning of coordinate system in geometry

Tags: geometry, notation, computational-geometry

I am trying to understand projective geometry to build a 3d scanner, using this text.

http://mesh.brown.edu/byo3d/notes/byo3D.pdf

When describing an idea pinhole camera it says

> In the ideal pinhole camera... the center of projection $o$ is at the
>   origin of the world coordinate system, with coordinates $(0; 0; 0) ^t$
>   , and the point $q$ and the vectors $v1$ and $v2$ are deﬁned as
>
> $ [v1 \vert v2 \vert q] = $$ \left[\begin{array}{ccc} 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 &
>  1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{array}\right]$$ $

My questions are what does the notation of $[v1 \vert v2 \vert q]$ mean?  Is this a single matrix or is it short hand for defining three column vectors?
Also in terms of meaning, why is this the identity matrix?

Comment: It's fairly common to write matrices as a list of column vectors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the linked PDF, section 2.2 ("Geometric Representations"):

> The $3\times N$ matrix resulting from concatenating $N$ vectors $v_1,\ldots,v_N$ as columns is denoted $\left[v_1\middle|\cdots\middle| v_N\right]$.